# How to use sed to find and replace a semantic version in a file?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to find and replace a version string in one of my files, but I can't seem to get the regex down right.

If I hard code the value, it works fine. I am trying the following, but nothing is changing in the file:

```
sed -i '' "s/Version: [0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/Version: $VERSION/g" file.php
```

The following works without any issues, but this won't be `1.0.0` forever, so the value cannot be hardcoded:

```
sed -i '' "s/Version: 1\.0\.0/Version: $VERSION/g" file.php
```

Contents of `file.php`:

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: Plugin
 * Description: Description for this product.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Tested up to: 6.2
 */
```

Comment: Don't escape the `+` character.

Comment: `\+` means 'literally a plus'. Take out the backslash to mean 'one or more'

Comment: @match That's backslash, not forward slash.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of lines from `file.php`; 3-5 lines should suffice, making sure (at least) one has a `Version:` line; can the file contain multiple lines that match on `Version:`?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
version=1.2.3
sed -i '' -E "s/ Version: [0-9.]+/Version: $version/g" file.php
```

Remainder for those that need it (OP seems to know ;) )

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
export VERSION='2.3.4'
perl -i.bak -pe 's{(Version:\s+)\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+}{$1$ENV{VERSION}}g' infile
```

`(Version:\s+)` : literal string `Version:` followed by 1 or more whitespace characters. Parentheses capture the matched pattern into match variable, here `$1`.
`\d+` : 1 or more digits.
`[.]` : literal dot (`.`). You can also use `\.`.
`$1$ENV{VERSION}` : the contents of the match variable `$1` followed by the environment variable `$VERSION`.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

**See also:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)